# How to store array of linked lists in a binary file?

Tags: c, data-structures

[image]

I would like to save an array of linked lists in a binary file, but I don't know how to assign the dynamic memory due to the varying lengths of linked lists for each bucket.

And to access a random position containing the whole linked list without reading the whole file, like a kind of index file?
Some tip?

Comment: That's a tricky assignment.  You're going to have to work out how to serialize items in the lists, then how to serialize each linked list, and then how to serialize an array of linked lists.  You'll need to design an on-disk structure that records the necessary information (after working out what the necessary information is).  You can't sensibly store any pointers, but physical proximity will do to give you the next (and previous).  You will need to store counts — for the size of the array, for the size of each list.  You may need to store offsets to the start of the lists.   Etc.

Comment: You also need to show what you got so far — what are the structures for the list items, the lists, and the array of lists in memory.  That will be important for converting to a serialized form on disk.  You also need to think about how you'd read the data back in from the file — that's the acid test for whether you've stored the information correctly.

Comment: It looks to me to be an issue of simply being able to serialize each item and a “null” item. Any kind of unique separator would do. Heck, even a CSV-style file would work.

Comment: I tend to use SQLite for persistent data storage these days. Come up with a table to store all the relevant data and functions to serialize/deserialize

Comment: Diego Enrique Molina Sanchez, "I would like to save an array of linked lists in a binary file" --> Since the data is primarily _strings_, not much advantage to use a binary file.  Consider a text file as it is easier to debug for a learner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will make these assumptions:

- Every (non-“null”) element of each list is an `int`
- There are `MAX_INT` or fewer elements in each list

Make your file (remember to open in binary mode) have the following structure:

- Output an `int` containing the number of items in the first list
- Output each `int` in that list
- Repeat for each subsequent list

This scheme has two drawbacks:

- each list has a (large) maximum number of elements
- you must traverse each list twice to save (first to learn the length, again to save each item)

It has the advantage of being very quick and direct to load.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple code,you can use fwrite to file and fread from file as you wish,but you must consider the `big-endian` or `little-endian`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _Node {
    struct _Node *next;
    int val;
} Node;

void serialize(Node arr[], int size[], int len) {

    FILE *f = fopen("serialize.bin", "wb");
    //write arr len
    fwrite(&len, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    //write array
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        //write linklist len
        fwrite(&size[i], sizeof(int), 1, f);
        Node *tmp = &arr[i];
        while (tmp) {
            fwrite(&tmp->val, sizeof(int), 1, f);
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}

Node *deserialize() {

    FILE *f = fopen("serialize.bin", "rb");
    int len;
    fread(&len, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    Node *ret = malloc(len * sizeof(Node));

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        int linklen;
        int val;
        Node *tmp = &ret[i];
        fread(&linklen, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        fread(&val, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        ret[i].val = val;
        ret[i].next = NULL;
        linklen--;

        while (linklen--) {
            fread(&val, sizeof(int), 1, f);
            tmp->next = malloc(sizeof(Node));
            tmp->next->next = NULL;
            tmp->next->val = val;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}


int main() {
#define ARRAY_LEN 3
    Node arr[ARRAY_LEN];
    int size[ARRAY_LEN];

    arr[0].next = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    arr[0].val = 1;
    arr[0].next->next = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    arr[0].next->val = 2;
    arr[0].next->next->next = NULL;
    arr[0].next->next->val = 3;
    size[0] = 3;

    arr[1].next = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    arr[1].val = 11;
    arr[1].next->next = NULL;
    arr[1].next->val = 22;
    size[1] = 2;

    arr[2].next = NULL;
    arr[2].val = 33;
    size[2] = 1;

    serialize(arr, size, ARRAY_LEN);

    Node *ret = deserialize();
    //TODO free memory

    return 0; //end of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not very complicated if there is a value that is never stored as an element in your linked list-- in that case, you can treat the linked list like a glorified null-terminated string, where whatever value that cannot exist in the linked list acts as the terminator. If you don't have such luxury, then you can write an extra byte with each value that determines if the value is the last one or not. Here's an implementation of the first possible solution, though it can be easily modified to work in the case of the second:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NODE_V_SIZE sizeof(int)

const int list_end = -1;

typedef struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node *prev, *next;
} Node;

void free_nodes(Node *head) {
    while (head) {
        Node *to_free = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(to_free);
    }
}

Node* new_node(int value) {
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (!node) {
        return NULL;
    }
    node->prev = NULL;
    node->next = NULL;
    node->value = value;
    return node;
}

int write_nodes(int fd, Node *head) {
    while (head) {
        if (write(fd, &head->value, NODE_V_SIZE) != NODE_V_SIZE) {
            return -1;
        }
        head = head->next;
    }
    if (write(fd, &list_end, NODE_V_SIZE) != NODE_V_SIZE) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

Node* read_nodes(int fd) {
    Node *head = NULL;
    Node *cur = NULL;
    int in;
    while (1) {
        if (read(fd, &in, NODE_V_SIZE) != NODE_V_SIZE) {
            free_nodes(head);
            return NULL;
        }
        if (in == list_end) {
            return head;
        }
        if (cur) {
            cur->next = new_node(in);
            if (!cur->next) {
                free_nodes(head);
                return NULL;
            }
            cur->next->prev = cur;
            cur = cur->next;
        } else {
            cur = new_node(in);
            if (!cur) {
                return NULL;
            }
            head = cur;
        }
    }
}

Node* new_random_list(int modifier) {
    Node *head = new_node(0);
    if (!head) {
        printf("out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Node *cur = head;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cur->next = new_node((i+modifier)*3);
        if (!cur->next) {
            free_nodes(head);
            printf("out of memory\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    
    return head;
}

int main() {
#define NHEADS 10
    // open file
    int fd = open("dat", O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        printf("failed to open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // make NHEADS number of 10 nodes linked together and write them to fd
    for (int i = 0; i < NHEADS; i++) {
        Node *head = new_random_list(i);
        if (write_nodes(fd, head)) {
            printf("failed to serialize nodes\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        free_nodes(head);
    }
    
    // read from fd to populate got then print it, repeat NHEADS times
    lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
    for (int i = 0; i < NHEADS; i++) {
        Node *got = read_nodes(fd);
        if (!got) {
            printf("failed to deserialize nodes\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        Node *head = got;
        
        while (got) {
            printf("%d\n", got->value);
            got = got->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
        
        free_nodes(head);
    }
    close(fd);
    
    return 0;
}
```